# Getting Out Variable Value From a For Looping PHP

Tags: php, for-loop

i have some problem when i use PHP for looping. Here the code:

```
$subsel = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM ar_subkategori, ar_subkategori_bhs WHERE ar_subkategori.id_subkategori = ar_subkategori_bhs.id_subkategori AND id_bahasa = 1 AND status = 'y'");
    while ($getsubsel = mysql_fetch_array($subsel)){
        if($getsubsel['id_subkategori_induk'] == 0){
            for($d = 0; $d < $cnt; $d++){
                $fetchit = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ar_subkategori WHERE id_subkategori = $detail_sub[$d]");
                $datafetch = mysql_fetch_array($fetchit);
                $id_values = $datafetch['id_subkategori'];
                if ($id_values == $getsubsel['id_subkategori']){
                    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' id='checkbox' value='$getsubsel[id_subkategori]' checked> <span style='font-size:10px; color:#FFA412;'>[ID: $getsubsel[id_subkategori]]</span> $getsubsel[nama_subkategori]</br>";
                }
            }
            if ($id_values != $getsubsel['id_subkategori']){
                echo "<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' id='checkbox' value='$getsubsel[id_subkategori]'> <span style='font-size:10px; color:#FFA412;'>[ID: $getsubsel[id_subkategori]]</span> $getsubsel[nama_subkategori]</br>";
            }
        } else {
            for($d = 0; $d < $cnt; $d++){
                $fetchit = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ar_subkategori WHERE id_subkategori = $detail_sub[$d]");
                $datafetch = mysql_fetch_array($fetchit);
                $id_values = $datafetch['id_subkategori'];
                if ($id_values == $getsubsel['id_subkategori']){
                    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' id='checkbox' value='$getsubsel[id_subkategori]' checked> <span style='font-size:10px; color:#FFA412;'>[ID: $getsubsel[id_subkategori]]</span> $getsubsel[nama_subkategori] <span style='color:#FFA412; font-style:italic; font-size:12px;'>*Ini adalah sub dari ID: $getsubsel[id_subkategori_induk]</span></br>";
                }               
            }
            if ($id_values != $getsubsel['id_subkategori']){
                echo "<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' id='checkbox' value='$getsubsel[id_subkategori]'> <span style='font-size:10px; color:#FFA412;'>[ID: $getsubsel[id_subkategori]]</span> $getsubsel[nama_subkategori] <span style='color:#FFA412; font-style:italic; font-size:12px;'>*Ini adalah sub dari ID: $getsubsel[id_subkategori_induk]</span></br>";
            }
        }
    }
```

And [here](http://s12.postimg.org/regf5msi5/ERROR.jpg) the capture from that code.

My question is, how to eliminate that multiple / dual data show? Thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: [`MySQL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) (`mysql_*` functions) extension is [***deprecated***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). I suggest to use [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (`mysqli_*` functions) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: What exactly is different in the logic withn `0` block from the logic within the `else` block? thats a lot of code and without the vars being in my native language or having intimate knowledge of the data it looks pretty much the same....

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `''` here `value='$getsubsel[id_subkategori]'`  like -  `value='$getsubsel[\'id_subkategori\']'` to make it working.

Dont stick to `mysql_*` learn `PDO` or move to `mysqli_*` as a sidenote.

Comment: Hi swapnesh, thanks for answering.. but, how about if i want to eliminate the unchecked checkbox.. not eliminate the the checked checkbox? Your solution is working, but the checked checkbox not show.

Comment: Only fetch those rows from the query whose checkbox are ticked

Comment: can you show me the code please? because I am a beginner, so I am a little confused. thank you.

Comment: @DimasAryaTejaKusumah in which field ur saving data for checkbox status?